# in and out variable in procedure calls

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure call as follows:

```
    DELIMITER // 
CREATE procedure getCustomer(NID varchar(200),Name varchar(200), OUT Flag INTEGER, OUT CID VARCHAR(200))  
BEGIN 
DECLARE id varchar(200); 
SET Flag = 0;
SET id = CONCAT(NID, '_' ,  Name); 
SELECT 1 INTO Flag FROM Customer WHERE customerID = id;
IF Flag = 1 THEN  
SET CID = id; 
ELSE
INSERT INTO Customer(NID, Name, customerID) VALUES(NID, Name, id); 
SET CID = id; 
END IF; 
END//
```

can you please tell me how to call IN, OUT variables in testing this procedure call?
or simply how to test this procedure call using exec proceudre_name(parameter) format?

Comment: Why store `customerID` in your `Customer` table at all, and not simply derive it from `NID` and `Name` on data retrieval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [`CALL` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/call.html):

> To get back a value from a procedure using an `OUT` or `INOUT` parameter, pass the parameter by means of a user variable, and then check the value of the variable after the procedure returns. (If you are calling the procedure from within another stored procedure or function, you can also pass a routine parameter or local routine variable as an `IN` or `INOUT` parameter.) For an `INOUT` parameter, initialize its value before passing it to the procedure. The following procedure has an `OUT` parameter that the procedure sets to the current server version, and an `INOUT` value that the procedure increments by one from its current value:
>
> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE p (OUT ver_param VARCHAR(25), INOUT incr_param INT)
> BEGIN
>   # Set value of OUT parameter
>   SELECT VERSION() INTO ver_param;
>   # Increment value of INOUT parameter
>   SET incr_param = incr_param + 1;
> END;
> ```
>
> Before calling the procedure, initialize the variable to be passed as the `INOUT` parameter. After calling the procedure, the values of the two variables will have been set or modified:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET @increment = 10;
> mysql> CALL p(@version, @increment);
> mysql> SELECT @version, @increment;
> +--------------+------------+
> | @version     | @increment |
> +--------------+------------+
> | 5.5.3-m3-log |         11 |
> +--------------+------------+
> ```

However, from your procedure it looks as though what you really want is to define a uniqueness constraint over the `customerID` column in your `Customer` table and then use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
ALTER TABLE Customer ADD UNIQUE (customerID);

INSERT INTO Customer
  (NID, Name, customerID)
VALUES
  (123, 'foobar', CONCAT(123, '_', 'foobar'))
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  NID = NID
;
```

Comment: I have tried the procedure locally as 

call getCustomer("1","BHUPI",@var1,@var2);

# NID, Name, customerID
  '1', 'BHUPI', '1_BHUPI'
it works for me thanks. 
but when I try to call the procedure from locally hosted server, it gives the following error: 

java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index of 3 is out of range (1, 0)

i dont really understand what is missing when i call the procedure, which basically is called as 
call getcustomer(?,?,?,?) 
and in xml file i supply the in and out variables. 
any suggestions might be helpful.

Comment: @Bhupi: As documented above, `OUT` and `INOUT` variables must be passed by means of [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html), which exist on the MySQL server and are associated with the client's connection; once the procedure has returned, you can obtain the values contained therein by way of a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: hey eggyal thanks, I found the error while calling the procedure. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Example using IN:

```
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE `procWithIN` (IN var1 INT)  
BEGIN  
    UPDATE someTable set fldname = fldname + var1;
END//

CALL procWithIN(10);
```

Example using OUT:

```
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE `procWithOUT` (OUT var1 VARCHAR(100))  
BEGIN  
    SET var1 = 'This is a test';  
END //

SET @someText = NULL;
CALL procWithOut(@someText);

-- do something with @someText (containing 'This is a test')
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fld=@someText
```

Example with INOUT

```
DELIMITER //  

CREATE PROCEDURE `procWithINOUT` (INOUT var1 INT)  
BEGIN  
    SET var1 = var1 + 100;  
END //

SET @someInt = 10;
CALL procWithINOUT(@someInt);
-- @someInt now contains 110
```